# Processing and then saving images with a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, image-processing, directory

I'm new in programming and I'd like to ask you how can I write my code so that it read all the pic whitin a directory, process it one by one, and then save the output images in another directory.

```
%pylab
%matplotlib inline
import cv2
import glob
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


filename = [img for img in glob.glob("outp/*.png")]
flist=sorted(filename)

images = []
for img in flist:
    n = cv2.imread(img, 0)
    images.append(n)
    blur = cv.GaussianBlur(n, (9,9), 0)
    cv.imwrite(flist, blur) #definitly wrong!! but idk how to do it
```

Comment: Any reason not to just use **ImageMagick** in Terminal? `mkdir outp` then `magick mogrify -path outp -blur XXXX *.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a list of all the pixel data of all the images in memory, that is just wasteful of memory. So, remove the lines:

```
images = []
```

and

```
images.apoend(...)
```

Then change your `imwrite()` to overwrite the current image:

```
cv2.imwrite(img,blur)
```

---

Here's a more complete version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import glob
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Go to where the images are
os.chdir('outp')

# Get list of filenames to convert
files = glob.glob("*.png")

for file in files:
    n = cv2.imread(file, 0)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(n, (9,9), 0)
    cv2.imwrite('blurred_' + file, blur)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about the list. But I think you've missed the point! My problem is about how should I write the imwrite() part

Comment: Maybe you can explain what you are trying to write in simple English then we'll get it turned into code. For the moment, all I can see is something that isn't what you want.

Comment: Ok. I have this direction with a lot pictures into it. I try to apply on all this images the Gaussian blur and then I would like to save all these blurred images in another 'output' directory

Comment: If you have a directory full of input images that you want to blur, why are you globbing the contents of the output directory?

Comment: Oh ok, I see our misunderstanding. I've called "outp" the directory with imput images inside.

Comment: Ok, so at the start,change directory to where the images are and then run your glob without the `outp` prefix, so it will just give you simple filenames. Then, in your `cv2.imwrite()` prefix the output directory onto the front of the filename.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time Mark. Unfurnatly I think i dont have fully understand what you mean. Can you modify your answer for show me how should I write the code?

Comment: I have updated my answer - please take another look.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:
`cv2.imwrite("mypicture.jpg", gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])`

Comment: I don't understand what it's supposed to do

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's lacking any explanation.  Please update your answer to explain why it's correct.

Comment: what is even `gray`?