# How to sort the images using one of the average pixels in python PIL

Tags: python, image, sorting, python-imaging-library, pixel

I'm on the way to sorting several images according to their average pixel values using PIL. In the below code I choose to pick up the average red value as the prameter to sort the images. The images are all in 640 x 480 RBG format. I have 10 images (from GRK_image1 to GRK_image10), instead of typing the code below 10 times, is there any faster way to loop through all the 10 images in one step and get all the average red values for each image? I have been stuck here for many days. Thank you!

```
from PIL import Image
import glob

# 1. Get the first picture, open it

first_image=Image.open('GRK_imge1.png')

all_pixels = []
for x in range(640):
  for y in range(480):
    R, G, B = first_image.getpixel((x,y))
    all_pixels.append(R)


storeAllImages = []

AverageR = (sum(all_pixels)/len(all_pixels))
print(AverageR)

storeAllImages.append(('GRK_image1.png',AverageR))
print(storeAllImages)
```

Comment: What is `convert_first_image`? How did you know about this `getpixel` method? Did you find a documentation page with a list of methods to manipulate the image? Is one of those methods able to get you a 2d array with all the pixel values?

Comment: In order to calculate the average of the red pixels, you only need to know a) what they sum up to and b) how many pixels there are. You do not need to hold a list of millions of values in memory. Also, you really should try to avoid using `for` loops to iterate over pixels - they are slooooooow and error-prone - try to use Numpy or OpenCV or something vectorised. Hint - you have imported `glob` - use it to gather your filenames.

Comment: @Stef, sorry that was an error made by me..I was supposed to change a RBGA format image into a RBG format so I did a converting step. Now I have already changed this 'convert_first_iamge' into 'first_image'. This 'getpixel' method is an existing function for the PIL library, which allows me to get the pixel values of the images. The link [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-getpixel-method/) I am not sure when you say 2d array with all the pixel values, what do you mean by that? sorry I am quite new to pyhton

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you! I see this glob has a glob.glob can open all the filenames that the same time, is that the right direction?

Comment: Yes... something similar here to look at... https://stackoverflow.com/a/60581605/2836621

Answer (score 1):

I would use skimage to load all the files at once using some pattern - in my case all the files are cars1.jpg, car2.jpg, etc so I use `'car*.jpg'`

This gives a list of 3d arrays, and I can take the mean of the red channel (the first of the 3 dimensions) as a key to `sorted` with the `reverse=True` flag to go from most red to least.

You can view some of them to make sure it's working, then save them, using `enumerate` to label.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.io import imread_collection, imshow, imsave

images = sorted(imread_collection("car*.jpg", conserve_memory=False), 
                key=lambda x: np.mean(x[:,:,0]), 
                reverse=True)

# to view your work
for i in images:
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(i)

# save images starting with most red
for c, i in enumerate(images):
    imsave(f'most_red_{c}.jpg', i)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Chris, many thanks, my images are in different formats and names, they are .png and .jpg format with own name. Now I use glob.glob to open all. After this, still, I haven't gotten the idea of how the pixels are added together(or how the pixels are stored all into a list so I can make an average calculation). Ideally, I like the images to be reorganized on a new image surface with sorted red pixel values. Is there any way I can do this without using NumPy and matplotlib? Thank you for help, I feel the solution is already partly in your answer, especially this 'mean as a key' part

Comment: the imread is using glob under the hood i'm pretty sure.  You can change the car*.jpg to just `./images/*` or whatever your images folder is.  matplotlib is just so I could show you the results, it is not needed.  I have no idea how you'd do this w/o numpy.  The code I have shared sorts them by red, and saves them in that order.